# What are the differences between "demens" and "insanus"? Are there any single Latin words (nouns) for "insane person"?

Tags: word-comparison, adjective, noun

First, I'm struggling with understanding the difference between *demens* and *insanum*.

My understanding is that *demens* is an adjective (*insane*). I've also seen *insanum* in a few online dictionaries ([here's an example](https://worldofdictionary.com/dict/latin-english/meaning/demens-inasnum)), but I'm not certain it's even a real word.

Second, I'm trying to find a *single word* (a noun) for *insane person* (if there is even such a thing), but I'm not sure whether it's *insanis* or *insanus* because they both, once again, appear to be adjectives.

P.S. Now that it's been pointed out to me that there is, in fact, no such word as *inasnum* (it's *insanus*), I would still like to know the difference between it and *demens*.

Comment: @brianpck I appreciate the edit but, as you can see in the crazy link I provide, it is spelled "inasnum," not "insanum" for whatever reason... :(

Comment: Sorry for the sloppy edit. I can say pretty confidently that this is a typo for the very common word [*insanus*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dinsanus). Why not use a more reputable site for a Latin dictionary?

Comment: @brianpck No worries. :) What would you say is the most dependable dictionary out there?

Comment: I edited the spelling again, @mig81. I don't know why that site hasn't corrected their own spelling, but it's better to have it spelled correctly here for people searching for similar questions. Also, a portion of us here will likely be driven _insanus_ every time we see it spelled wrong. :)  My edit was also somewhat sloppy, so if you wanted you could remove the bits related to the misspelled word.

Comment: For recommended dictionaries see the post regarding [what are the best online latin dictionaries](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/867/which-online-latin-dictionaries-should-i-use-and-why).

Comment: @Adam Thank you! :)

Comment: @brianpck It's all good. So, two questions remain: What is the difference between _demens_ and _insanus_ and is there a noun for _insane person_?

Comment: @vectory Honestly, I have no idea what you're talking about. Entschuldigung! ;) I am looking for a word in Latin similar to the Russian _псих_ (n.), if it helps. (Having said this, it still seems to translate to _insanis_, which is still an adjective, not a noun...)